# Can you delete-min from fibonacci heap in O(1) amortized?

Tags: data-structures, amortized-analysis

I just had a data-structures exam. One of the questions asked us to create a data structure which allowed insert operations in O(logn) amortized and delete-max (or min, doesn't matter) in O(1) amortized.
The official answer was to use a regular fibonacci heap, and then to change the potential s.t. for every insert we increase the potential by logn (instead of 1) and then for every delete max we can decrease the potential by logn.
In other words, we pay for the deletions with the insertions.
To me, this seems a illegitimate, because at the end of the day each deletion will still cost O(logn) at least. Am I misunderstanding something, or is this really a bad question?

Comment: Why doesn't a binary heap suffice? Pick a potential function $\Phi(n) = n \log n$. Charge each insert operation $\Theta(\log n)$ amortized time. This will account for the $O(\log n)$ time actually spend during the insertion and for an increase of $\Phi(n+1)-\Phi(n)=O(\log n)$ in the potential. Charge the delete-min operation $\Theta(1)$ amortized time. The actual deletion will take $O(\log n)$ time, which you can pay for with the $\Phi(n) - \Phi(n-1) = n \log n - (n-1) \log (n-1) = \Omega( \log n )$ decrease in potential.

Comment: Also a legitimate solution. What bothers me is that in both these cases we calculate the potential starting from an empty structure. This just seems to me to be meaningless because if this is so we can say that any deletion from any structure is O(1) amortized because we pay for them with insertions.

Comment: That's totally fine, as long as in the data structure you're using deletions are not more expensive than insertions (otherwise you'll have to charge more amortized time for the insertions).

Comment: okay thanks for the clarification